# Recursive observable method with delay

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I am trying to create recursive server connection method with delay in Angular 8.

I tried this:

```
public connectToServerSafely(): Observable<boolean> {
  if (this.isConnecting) {
    return this.connectToServerSafely().pipe(delay(5000));
  } else if (this.isConnected) {
    return of(true);
  } else {
    return this.connectToServer();
  }
}
```

Where connectToServer method returns Observable< boolean> depends on connection succeed or failed.

The problem is this delay method, I do not know why but I am facing with almost 2000 calls of  connectToServerSafely() method until connection established. Connection is established after 1 second.

Why delay method does not really postopone recursive call of connectToServerSafely method  (something as setTimeout method does)?

Comment: Where are you  setting `isConnecting` and `this.isConnected`

Comment: `delay` operator delays the emission of values from the source observable. It doesn't block the calling code in any way.

Comment: Those parameters are set in connectToServer() method. The first line of this method is this.isConnecting = true. And when connection is established we set this.isConnected = true and this.isConnecting = false....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution works for me:

```
public connectToServerSafely(): Observable<boolean> {
  if (this.isConnecting) {
    return new Observable((observer) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.connectToServerSafely().subscribe(result => {
            observer.next(result);
            observer.complete();
          });
        }, 500);
      });
  } else if (this.isConnected) {
    return of(true);
  } else {
    return this.connectToServer();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`this.connectToServerSafely().pipe(delay(5000))` will **not stop** the function from calling itself. The `delay` operator will just **delay** the **emitted values**.

Here's my approach:

```js
let isConnecting = true;
let isConnected = false;

timer(2000)
  .subscribe(() => (isConnecting = false, isConnected = true));

function connSafely ()/* : Observable<any> */ {
  console.warn('calling `connSafely`');

  if (isConnecting) {
    return timer(500).pipe(concatMap(() => connSafely()))
  }

  if (isConnected) {
    return of(true);
  }

  return connectToServer();
}

function connectToServer () {
  isConnecting = true;

  return of('connecting');
}

connSafely().subscribe();
```

`console.warn("calling 'connSafely'")` should be called 5 times(1 for **initial function call** one 4 because 2000 / 500 = 4).

**Note**: It is important that you use one of the [higher-order mapping operators](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/)(`switchMap`, `concatMap`, `mergeMap`/`flatMap`, `exhaustMap`) in order to make sure that all the subsequent function calls are automatically subscribed to/unsubscribed from.

Try to use  `tap(() => connSafely())` and you should only see message twice in the console.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rx-playground). (*scroll down until you find your example*)

Comment: Thanks.
Example you send to me on StackBlitz, has error 'Maximum call stack size exceeded' :)

Comment: Sorry!.. I forgot to save :D. Should be fixed in a few minutes.

Comment: For some reason, it won't record any new saved code. I don't know what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

so looks like you  set `this.isConnecting` and `this.isConnected` some where at the subscription to stream. If so code run async and you  exit condition does not work because you design it on sync way

```
public connectToServerSafely(): Observable<boolean> {
  if (this.isConnecting) {
    // here function will be called until this.isConnecting change to false
    return this.connectToServerSafely().pipe(delay(5000));
  } else if (this.isConnected) {
    return of(true);
  } else {
    return this.connectToServer();
  }
}
```

Comment: This is ok to be called I want that, but why this call is not postponed for 5 seconds. And next call come after 5 second ? Currently I have  2000 calls in 1 second ?

Comment: @Milos I think this happens because here `this.connectToServerSafely().pipe(delay(5000));`first of all you do  api call  and then delay. That mean api will be called  but result  will be delayed

Comment: That is maybe problem, how to postpone whole API call then ?

Comment: You can try something like this `timer(5000).pipe(switchMap(() =>this.connectToServerSafely()))`. But it's not a right solution because after 5sec you'll got batch of requests

Comment: I tried with timeout, but that is not good solution (actually it does not work at all), since timeout cannot be return as observable...
Must be something appropriate to this kind of problem

Comment: I think better solution here  is use Angular interceptor and  also use `retryWhen` operator in which pass cb which count attempts(to be able to limit attempts)  and  return timer